# What type of hydraulic oil is used in the aviation industry?

Tags: commercial-aviation, aircraft-maintenance, fuel, aerospace-materials

Among the three different types of hydraulic fluid types (mineral based/petroleum based, synthetic esters, naturally occurring vegetable oils) which one is used in the aviation industry and why?

Comment: Define "better". The companies that promote these witches brews generally propose stuff that is as complicated and proprietary as possible, because the more proprietary it is, the more profit everybody makes. Often simple substances are the best choice for the consumer, but nobody makes a profit selling cheap generic materials that anybody can get at a hardware store, like mineral oil. So, are you talking about what is good for the manufacturers or the operators?

Comment: Better for what? Brake systems? Ground trucks? This is way too broad.

Comment: Way too broad? OP mentions aviation industry, is that not within the scope of the Aviation Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Koyovis it's closed as too broad, not off topic.

Comment: @fooot Yes I see that. I just cannot see what is too broad about asking which hydraulic fluids are used in the aviation industry. ATA chapter 29 deals with Hydraulic Systems on board of aircraft. Hydraulic systems are used for brakes, flying controls, landing gear extension, engine control etc: they have a broad use in the aviation industry  Like all systems designed for on-board use, there are specific design rules for airborne hydraulic systems, including stipulations on the hydraulic fluids for the aviation industry. OP's question is perfectly valid,

Comment: Apparently [lemonade](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25506/8730) is a good choice

Comment: General Aviation brakes and gear systems use a mineral based brake fluid that conforms to MIL-H-5606A. Here’s more info. http://us-packaging.com/documents/phillips66/aviation_products/66_5606H_5606A_Avia_fld.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the aviation industry, flammability is a major concern, and aviation hydraulic systems require Fluids that cannot burn yet don't create corrosion and still lubricate. [Skydrol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skydrol) for instance is a phosphate based ester, a nasty substance that irritates the skin, but at least has some flame resistance.

Old hydraulic motion systems on simulators used the stuff, later ones went to mineral oils like Shell Tellus. If there is an oil leak in a pressure hose, a fine mist of fluid droplets appears, flammable if mineral oil but this could be handled in a ground facility with extinguishers everywhere. Not a good circumstance in an aviation accident though, and that is why in aircraft the esters have to be used.

Vegetable oils are not used for hydraulic systems in the aviation industry at this moment as far as I am aware.

Comment: It all comes from [Swissair Flight 306](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swissair_Flight_306). That accident moved the authorities to demand only flame resistant hydraulic fluids. By the way, here is [more inside info](https://www.pprune.org/aviation-history-nostalgia/416029-swissair-caravelle-disaster-zurich-1963-a.html) on that accident.